# unable to update to default values null and empty string for tinyint and varchar fields

Tags: mysql, varchar, tinyint

I have the following table schema -

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `pre_notif_action` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `pre_notif_interval` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uuid_UNIQUE` (`uuid`),

  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

For an existing record, with values "predeactivate" and 45 in the fields pre_notif_action and pre_notif_interval respectively -

```
mysql> select pre_notif_action, pre_notif_interval 
       from tablename 
       where uuid="1887826113857166800";
```

Result -

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| pre_notif_action | pre_notif_interval |
+------------------+--------------------+
| predeactivate    |                 45 |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

When I try to edit, I get non zero affected rows -

```
 update prepaid_account 
 set pre_notif_action="" 
     and pre_notif_interval=NULL 
 where  uuid="1887826113857166800";
```

Result -

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

However, when I select -

```
mysql> select pre_notif_action, pre_notif_interval 
       from prepaid_account 
       where uuid="1887826113857166800";
```

I get this output -

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| pre_notif_action | pre_notif_interval |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 0                |                 45 |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya There is some update happening. It's not like change not applying at all.

Comment: Same results. Why do you ask single quotes?

Comment: Instead of `AND` in the `SET` clause use a comma, if you want to change several columns. And yes, you should use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue here is the use of AND in the SET clause. I think your query is being interpreted like this:

```
update prepaid_account 
 set pre_notif_action = ("" and pre_notif_interval=NULL)
 where  uuid="1887826113857166800";
```

The `("" and pre_notif_interval=NULL)` is being interpreted as a boolean, which is why `0` is inserted into the field (`0` being the equivalent of boolean `false` in MySQL). To fix this, use a comma between multiple fields in the SET clause as follows:

```
update prepaid_account 
 set pre_notif_action = "", pre_notif_interval=NULL
 where  uuid="1887826113857166800";
```

Answer (score 1):

You get pre_notif_action = 0 as result or logical operation:

```
pre_notif_action="" 
 and pre_notif_interval=NULL
```

that return 0 (false)

So you are using a logical operation and not the setting for update the two columns `pre_notif_action` and `pre_notif_interval`.

The proper syntax for updated  several columns is values seperated  by comma as:

```
 update prepaid_account 
 set pre_notif_action="" 
     , pre_notif_interval=NULL 
 where  uuid="1887826113857166800";
```